# How can I make an NSDictionary contain a selector as one of its values?

Tags: objective-c

This code is in a UITableViewController subclass viewDidLoad method.  The UITableViewController subclass contains a test method.

It crashes without throwing an exception.

```
id dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"some text", @"text", @selector(test), @"selector", nil]
```

Answer (score 14):

pix0r's solution is good, but I usually prefer to use strings because they're more resilient to serialization and make the dictionary easier to read in debug output.

```
// Set selector
SEL inSelector = @selector(something:);
NSString *selectorAsString = NSStringFromSelector(inSelector);
id dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some text", @"text", selectorAsString, @"selector", nil];

// Retrieve selector
SEL outSelector = NSSelectorFromString([dict objectForKey:@"selector"]);
```

Comment: I agree with this. SEL maps more naturally to a string (since it's a name) than a value (which usually represents C scalars and structs).

Comment: Also, you could ship a string down from a service if you're open to playing risky games like that.

Answer (score 5):

Use `NSValue` to wrap the selector:

```
// Set selector
SEL inSelector = @selector(something:);
NSValue *selectorAsValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&inSelector objCType:@encode(SEL)];
id dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some text", @"text", selectorAsValue, @"selector", nil];

// Retrieve selector
SEL outSelector;
[(NSValue *)[dict objectForKey:@"selector"] getValue:&outSelector];
// Now outSelector can be used as a selector, e.g. [self performSelector:outSelector]
```

Comment: As a follow up, NSValue is the correct class for wrapping any non-object type in an object. NSPoint, NSRect and NSSize all have dedicated constructors and number types are wrapped by the subclass NSNumber but you can also wrap arbitrary structs and even wrap objects without retaining them.

Note though... NSValue is for *typed* data. Arbitrary blocks of binary data should be wrapped by NSData.

Comment: This begs for a category on NSValue